# Can't switch Workbook with InputBox to select range

Tags: c#, excel, excel-2010, vsto

I'm currently programming an excel add in for Excel 2010 (Version 14.0.7208.5000 32-Bit). According to Malick, the following problem does not appear in Excel 2016.

At one point in the program I need the user to select a range. Therefor i use an Excel._Application.Inputbox, which is started by pressing a button within a form.

I can select ranges on different worksheets, but I can only change the workbook if there's a way to click in it. So if the main workbook in which i started the add in is in fullscreen, i cant get to the second workbook with the data in it.

```
public void main()
{
    Parameters Paras = new Parameters();
    Paras.ShowDialog();
    //Some calculations with these parameters follow here
}
```

Clicking a button in that form starts a form for advanced settings/data slection:

```
private void btn_Advanced_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ParametersAdvanced PA = new ParametersAdvanced();
    PA.Show();
}
```

One of the settings is for custom timestamps:

```
private void btn_Time_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Excel.Range TimeRange = GetRange();
    rTB_Time.Text = TimeRange.Address;    //display range in a RichTextBox
}
```

Now when that following InputBox is open, I can't switch to another workbook.

```
public Excel.Range GetRange()
{
    Excel.Application xlApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Application;

    Selection:
    Excel.Range rng = xlApp.InputBox("Select Range", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 8);

    if (rng.Columns.Count == 1)
        return rng;
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Select only one column with according values.");
        goto Selection;
}
```

P.S.: I also don't like the goto, but didn't figure out a way to work around using it.

Comment: I cannot replicate you problem with Excel 2016 (Office 365 - build 16.0.93330.2073). I can change of workbook when the input box is open just by clicking the Excel logo in the windows (bottom) toolbar.